# Permitir caracteres especiais como entrada de teclado Java

Tags: java

Estou usando o Scanner para ler alguns dados do teclado, porém, acentos e caracteres especiais não são identificados.

Por exemplo: João e Maurício aparecem com um quadradinho na letra acentuada, porém, se eu digitar essas palavras na saída em tela não tem problemas. Aparecem certinho.

Tentei com `static Locale PORTUGUESE;` mas não deu certo.

Como posso fazer pra isso funcionar?

Obrigado

EDIT

---

Meu código está assim no momento:

```
package Trabalho_final;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Funcionario 
{
    private String nome, email, telefone;
    private float salario;

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");

          //............ restante do código
```

Comment: Coloca o código que você já tem para que possamos ajudar. Outra dúvida, esta executando o teu programa no `cmd` ou no `console da IDE` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utlize o construtor do `Scanner` com, sobrecarga de *encoding*, da seguinte maneira: `Scanner skener=new Scanner(file,"ISO-8859-1");` caso esteja lendo de um arquivo ou `Scanner skener=new Scanner(System.in,"ISO-8859-1");` caso esteja lendo da entrada padrão.

A seguir veja um exemplo completo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerCharactersWithAccent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read line
        System.out.println("Por favor, entre com os caracteres a serem lidos na próxima linha:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in,"ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

        // print line
        System.out.println("Caracteres lidos na linha anterior: " + scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: o que seria o file?

Comment: questão corrigida :)

Comment: Caso a solução tenha respondido a sua questão, por favor, clique na seta verde em cima da resposta. Obrigado :)

Comment: Opa, Eduardo. Desculpe a demora, não tinha tido tempo de conferir aqui ainda. Então, não resolveu =/ nem com a sobrecarga de encoding. Tem mais alguma sugestão? Vou colocar o código ali em cima

Comment: Caro @MaximilianoMeyer, modifiquei a resposta. Acredito que agora funcione. Por favor, teste e me avise do resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Testei aqui e funcionou assim (baseado na resposta do colega):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read line
        System.out.println("Por favor, entre com os caracteres a serem lidos na próxima linha:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in,"CP850");

        // print line
        System.out.println("Caracteres lidos na linha anterior: " + scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

`CP850` é a codificação padrão do Prompt de Comando.

---

Existe também a opção de modificar a codificação do prompt de comando através do comando `chcp 1252` (para a codificação Windows-1252) após o mesmo aberto
ou chamá-lo já com essa codificação com o comando `cmd.exe 1252`.

Fonte e mais informações: [Caracteres especias Prompt de Comando](http://caixaseca.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/caracteres-especiais-no-prompt-de.html)

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição, Shura, mas testei aqui e ele distorceu os caracteres. O "til", por exemplo, "ã" virou "Ò".